# How to intersect 2 polygon layers with a given tolerance for features in different layers only?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, geoprocessing

I can intersect 2 layers with polygons using ArcMap. However I can specify only overall tolerance no matter what layer a feature is in (even same layer). So I either end up with lots of slivers if I don't tolerate snapping, or I end up collapsing small features from the first layer that I'd want to keep.

The problem is that I would like for features let's say less than 10 m apart in the first layer to stay as they are if they happen to be contained within some polygon of the second layer. However I'd like for edges of polygons of the 2nd layer to snap to those in the first layer if they are within 10 m.

I'm open to a solution using any tool be it ArcMap or some python library/script.

Here is the rough idea of what I want.

[image]

Comment: Can you add some screenshots/drawings to try to explain your situation visually?

Comment: Are you already using [geodatabase topology rules](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001t000000sp000000.htm) at all? Can you post a sample dataset? If you need a file host, see this [meta thread](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/900/gis-se-approved-hosts-for-example-datasets) for hosting suggestions.

Comment: Which version of ArcGIS are you using?

Comment: I'm using 9.3.1 with ArcInfo license. Yeah... I guess I missed that part on cluster tolerance. As for the data, I'd have to crop & strip it. I feel like topology rules is all I need...

Comment: If you do find some rules that work I would encourage you to post your solution as an answer. It definitely sounds like a tricky problem!

Comment: Perhaps I was too optimistic. I don't work with topologies on day by day basis. I thought I could specify one tolerance for the first layer and make the 2nd one to snap automagically using larger tolerance. It does not look like something that can be done with topology and rules alone:(

Comment: Can you describe your steps a little more precisely? You say "I can intersect 2 layers with polygons using ArcMap" but do you mean that you have tried to use the Intersect tool with two feature classes or something else?  Your diagram is excellent and enables me to easily see what you want but I'm not clear on what you have tried.

Answer (score 3):

First run [Integrate](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.2/index.cfm?TopicName=integrate_%28data_management%29) on both layers with your desired cluster tolerance and ranks.

After this just run the [union tool](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.2/index.cfm?TopicName=union_%28analysis%29).

Important usage tip (from ESRI help):
Integrate permanently changes the input features. Integrate does not create new data, but, instead, modifies the original input features.

Comment: I saw *Integrate* previously. It looks like it can adjust vertices only. Perhaps I should have given a better visual example. I'll update the question. I feel like there is no silver bullet. I feel like I'd have to use *Spatial Adjustment* with *Edge Snapping* and then *Intersect* followed by *Eliminate* tool. For *Eliminate* I'd have to figure out what I can call as a sliver I guess something based on area over square perimeter ratio.